# Using jQuery to manage Database populated Filter name to display a few portfolio items

Tags: jquery, html, whitespace

I have a product page where I have created a filter to sort the product list by its category.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tab").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    if (value == "all") {
      //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
      $('.filter').show('1000');
    } else {
      $(".filter").not('.' + value).hide('3000');
      $('.filter').filter('.' + value).show('3000');
    }
  });

  if ($(".tab").removeClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  }

  $(this).addClass("active");
```

Everything works fine, but I have one category named "Power Tool", and only this filter not working for me. I suspect the problem is the whitespace between 'power' and 'tools'.

You can see this code working here: http://www.buildersmart.net/products.php

Comment: If this is a "php/mysql" question, code for those tags need to be included, and/or show relevance. If everything in "php/mysql" works as you say *"everything works fine"*, then those tags should be omitted, only if this isn't related. There's also no "html" here.

Comment: If you have whitespace, try using `trim()` should this be what it's about.

Comment: So if you suspect the space is the problem, have you tried removing the space...?

Comment: Sorry @RoryMcCrossan, But I am not sure how to do that, as I don't have much coding experience. But I could understand that outside from a programmer's point of view.  I do UI Design and very basic coding part. Thank You for your suggestion.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, Thank You for your input, I have noted your comment. And I would be more subject specific in tag selection and clarifying my requirement from next time. Thank You!

Comment: @BranforgeCreativeStrategies Welcome. Glad to see the answer given provided you with the solution, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the magic for the case you have.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".tab").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            value = value.split(' ').join('.');
        if (value == "all") {
          //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
          $('.filter').show('1000');
        } else {
          $(".filter").not('.' + value).hide('3000');
          $('.filter').filter('.' + value).show('3000');
        }
      });

      if ($(".tab").removeClass("active")) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
      }

      $(this).addClass("active");
```

Note: value = value.split(' ').join('.');

This piece of code will remove the spaces with dots. So "Power Tools" will become "Power.Tools". Then jQuery selector can pick it up like

```
$('.Power.Tools').show('3000');
```

Comment: Can you outline *what* you did exactly? It would help everyone to know that, without having to compare.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes just look at the note section added now at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. Well, let's see what the OP says and hope it fixes it :)

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadTashfeen, Its works perfect for me!. Thanks for getting my question clearly and providing the right answer. Your just awesome!!